how can I save and continue if WebDriverWait did not find the class
I want that if WebDriverWait didn’t find what it was looking for, continue the cycle and save it in the database, I tried giving the src_iframe variable and checking if not src_iframe but it didn’t help
try:
    drivers.get(film_url)

    iframe = WebDriverWait(drivers, 8).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cinemaplayer-iframe"))
    )

    src_iframe = WebDriverWait(drivers, 8).until(
        lambda d: iframe.get_attribute('src') != ''
    )
    
    if not src_iframe:
        film_instance.is_completed2 = True
        film_instance.save()
        continue


You just need to get your try/except clauses inthe right place

Expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt may help here?:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(org.openqa.selenium.By)  Try/catch and assume the catch is telling you it's not available and do whatever you like there.  If it succeeded then the driver's context will be inside the iframe.
